# Connect 2 Routers Wirelessly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

(If this isn't the best site for this, let me know and I'll move it)

I just moved into a new house that is lacking in coax and ethernet outlets, so I was forced to put our modem and router on the first floor. I decided to put my desktop on the second floor in the office. It has a wireless card in it already so I was hoping the signal wouldnt be too bad, but its pretty much unusable.

I have 2 wireless routers and a desktop. Is there any way I can have the primary router on the first floor broadcast to the secondary router upstairs, then plug the desktop into the upstairs router? Here is a diagram (blue lines = ethernet):

[image]

Primary router on first floor: [Netgear R6200v2](http://support.netgear.com/product/R6200v2)

Secondary router on 2nd floor: [Linksys WRT54GS](http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/routers/WRT54GS)

Answer (score 2):

Yes; This is called *wireless bridging*. It requires special support on the router that is operating as the wireless client bridge (the one connected to your desktop), but many 3rd-party firmwares (Tomato, DD-WRT) support this properly.

Comment: Quick question, do the two routers need to be the same? This page (http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=4194) says"NOTE: When the WAP54G access point is set to wireless bridge mode, it will only communicate with another Linksys Wireless-G Access Point (WAP54G)."

Comment: The routers don't need to be the same, you just have to put the second one into bridge mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can, it is called wireless bridging.

A site with instructions for how to do it, is here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/howto-connect-two-wireless-router-wirelessly-bridge-with-open-source-software/